# LWC setCustomValidity in the child Component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforce1-app

In my custom LWC page adding the dynamic rows, on change of 'passoptions' value combo box base on the value selection need to show the mandatory error message.

the other field is the lookup field which is the child component.

Getting following error `Uncaught TypeError: t.setCustomValidity is not a function throws`  for the below code Can anyone help me on this

**Parent Component**

**Html:**

```
<lightning-combobox
    class="passoptions"
    variant="label-hidden"
    name="passoptions"
    options={passoptionsValue}
    onchange={handlePass}
></lightning-combobox>


<c-auto-lookup
    data-key={ad.key}
    class="Country"
    selectedval={ad.CountryValue}
    objectlabel="Search Country"
    onrecordselection={handleCountryChange}
    data-class="Country"
    recordkey={ad.key}
></c-auto-lookup>
```

**JS**

```
handlevalidateCountry(lane) {
    let passOptions = this.template.querySelectorAll(".Country").forEach((element) => {
        if (element.dataset.key == lane.key) {
            if (lane.passThrough == 'Site') {
                    
                var objCountry = this.allCountriesList.find(countryelement => {
                    return countryelement.recId == lane.originCountryValue;
                });
               
                if (objCountry.recName != 'N/A') {
                    element.setCustomValidity("");
                    element.reportValidity();
                } else {
                    element.setCustomValidity("Value is Required");
                    element.reportValidity();
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

kindly let me know if any additional details needed

Comment: have you exposed 'setCustomValidity' method in  auto-lookup component by making it as @api?

Comment: not getting you bro

Comment: this.template.querySelectorAll(".Country") will return instance of 'c-auto-lookup' in your element varibale. if your c-auto-lookup component does not have setCustomValidity method then you wont be able to call it

Comment: element.checkValidity(); in the parent and  below code added in the child component 
`@api checkValidity() {
        var inputCmp = this.template.querySelector(".className");
        alert(inputCmp);
        var value = inputCmp.value;
        // is input is valid?
        if (!value) {
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity("Please Enter a valid Value");
        } else {
            inputCmp.setCustomValidity("dsds"); // if there was a custom error before, reset it
        }
        inputCmp.reportValidity();
    }`

Comment: Now the error message is not showing also the `setCustomValidity` is not aplying bro

Comment: Could you share the code of the child component `c-auto-lookup` as well ? Basic answer is you need to declare a `setCustomValidity` in your child component js and annotate with `@api` to make it visible. This child method will call the function on the underlying standard LWC component I guess you are using.